# Weka NominalToBinary makes test and training sets incompatible

Tags: data-mining, weka

So I have a training and testing sets and they contain multi-valued nominal values. As long as I need to train & test NaiveBayesMultinomial classifier, which doesn't support multi-valued nominal values, I do the following:

```
java weka.filters.supervised.attribute.NominalToBinary -i train.arff -o train_bin.arff -c last
java weka.filters.supervised.attribute.NominalToBinary -i test.arff -o test_bin.arff -c last
```

Then i run this:

```
java weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial -t train_bin.arff -T test_bin.arff
```

And the following error arises:

```
Weka exception: Train and test files not compatible!
```

As far as I understood after I examined both .arff files, they became incompatible after I ran NominalToBinary, since train and test sets are different and thus different binary variables are generated.

Is it possible to perform NominalToBinary conversion in a way that sets keep being compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the two sets into one, perform the NominalToBinary conversion, then split them again. This way, they should be normalized the same way.

But are you sure the files were compatible before? Or does maybe your test and/or training set contain attribute cases that the other doesn't have?

Comment: what classifier is able to work with multi-valued nominal?

And how can I concatenate and then split them in the same way?

Comment: I don't use classification or Weka much, so I can't give you the details. It's just that you always should normalize (and that includes binary conversion) test and training data exactly the same way. Usually, one does the split after preprocessing.